# how to remove AttributeError in Robobrowser

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, robobrowser

i'm trying to login to my college id and fetch some info using `robobrowser`.
bu i'm getting this traceback when i try to print contents of my dashboard.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/dictionary/RobobrowseErp.py", line 26, 
in <module>
    print(open.parsed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parsed'
```

here is my code.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import requests

start = requests.session()

token = 'value_of_token'
token_1 = 'value_of_token_1 '

stuff = {

   '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': token,
   'btnLogIn': 'Login',
   '__VIEWSTATE': token_1,
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'
}

start.headers = stuff


browser = RoboBrowser(parser='lxml', session=start)
browser.open('http://erp.college_name.edu/')
sign_in = browser.get_form(id='some_value')
sign_in['tbUserName'].value = 'myId'
sign_in['tbPassword'].value = 'myPass'
open = browser.submit_form(sign_in)
print(open.parsed)
```

here is the source code.

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="Welcome_iie.aspx" id="some_value" class="bgLogin">  <div class="formWrap">
                    <div class="error"> <span id="lblDispMessage"></span></div>
                        <div class="group">
                            <input name="tbUserName" type="text" id="tbUserName"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>Username</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                              <input name="tbPassword" type="password" id="tbPassword"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>Password</label>
                        </div>

                           <input type="submit" name="btnLogIn" value="Login" onclick="return validation();" id="btnLogIn" class="button buttonBlue used">
                    </div>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, so the reason i was getting an `AttributeError` because in simple language.. things are not being parsed from the object itself i.e. `opens` ,it is predefined that `robobrowser` is an automated browser, so every thing is being automated ,to whatever request or method or whatever code we write so we have to do,

```
print(browser.parsed)
```

instead of

```
print(opens.parsed)
```

thanks!